# Is it possible to convert the String value we are getting by intent via get string extra into integer with Integer.parseInt(String)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

```
String a=qw.getStringExtra("19");

int b= Integer.parseInt(a);
```

During Run time the application is getting crash

Comment: You mean: `String a=qw.getStringExtra("someStringName"); int b= Integer.parseInt(a);`

Comment: have you tried checking the value of `a`? I mean is it parseable to an `int`?

Comment: By String a=qw.getStringExtra("19");  , I mean that the value which I am catching in a is assingned the key 19
@FrankN.Stein

Comment: Yes it is Parseable to int @AbubakkarRangara

Comment: You can't use a number as a key. You can't even create a variable or a constant which name is 19 (or any other number).

Comment: In bundles, you have to store and retrieve values by key. For example, when you do putExtra(), you store "19" under some kind of key: `bundle.putExtra("numApples","19");`. If you then attempt to get the value "19" from the bundle, you must provide the bundle with a key to look up the value by: `bundle.getString("numApples");`. If bundle.get fails, it returns null. You're probably getting a null pointer exception when you attempt to parse an int from null.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein agree with you... but you can use `"19"` as a key... you agree also that? I think OP is being confused with name and value in the intent extra's

Comment: @JordiCastilla `you can use "19" as a key... you agree also that?` NO. You can use "19" as a **value**, not as a **key**. You can use "nineteen" as a key, though.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein why not, `"19"` is not a valid `String` or what? this is not a variable name....

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Jordi is right, you can use "19" as a key. It is a valid string.

Comment: @JordiCastilla Well, isn't a key a constant, after all?

Comment: nope, a key, in this case is a `String` and `"19"` is a valid one...

Comment: you're confusing you and OP with variable names, what is another different issue not related at all with nothing here

Comment: I always treated keys as constants to refer to in code (and I do use meaningful names for my keys)... oh, well, I learned something more!

Comment: you can do `String NINETEEN = "19";` and `putExtra(NINETEEN, 19)` but you can't use `String 19 = "19"`

Comment: Of course. This is what I said. But I'd use `putExtra("NINETEEN", 19)`

Comment: me too... is much more clear and readable, but at the end it's the same

Comment: Ok, this is what I learned today... you're free to make a mess, if you like to... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are trying to parse a `String` that does not match with an integer, in order to avoid this, use `NumberFormatException` thrown by [`parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

> **NumberFormatException -** if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

Also, "19" is the name of the extra you use to putExtra in your intent, right?

```
String a=qw.getStringExtra("19");  // 19 is the extra name, right???
int b = 0;
try {
    b= Integer.parseInt(a);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // tell error because extra string is not an integer number
}
```

Comment: @JordiCastilla  But the value which is assigned to the key is parseable to int it is -"10" ( Double quotes because I have declared it as String c="10";)

Comment: `"10"` is a correct `String` to be parsed as `int = 10`, my concern now is: you use, `putExtra("19", c)` when creating the intent? **REMEMBER: `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, EXTRA_VALUE)`** in your code, `getStringExtra("19")` you are calling an extra with `EXTRA_NAME = "19"`, you get my point?

Comment: you get it right it was just a silly mistake I am doing , Thanks

Comment: sweet to hear that!! @GauravJoshi don't complain or think a mistake is silly if it makes you understand a concept that you wont forget. When you're an experienced user, this is silly, but for beginners is a necessary step you must take. If you have time, please [read this great post](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems?cb=1)